# SOLR 3.6 and query-time join

Tags: solr

Does solr 3.6 support joining at all? According to http://java.dzone.com/articles/apache-lucene-and-solr-36 it does, but when i try to execute any join following the tutorial at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join all i get is an error "Unknown query type 'join'".
Does it need to be enabled somehow or is it simply not working in the 3.6 release?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a `Solr4.0` mark at http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join

its not available in 3.6

also see http://www.searchworkings.org/blog/-/blogs/query-time-joining-in-lucene
`there is a possibility that it will also be included in Lucene 3.6`

i guess it was not included